# How to combine multiple SQL tables with different data into one based on the latest date and retaining old data if new data is null?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a table based on five different tables and not all the tables contain the data I need. They only have two columns in common and I need to take the latest fields based on the date but if one of the fields contains data and the latest field is null I need to keep what is already there. The five tables are structured as follows.

```
TABLE_1
system_code 
user_id 
item_id
system_name 
date 

TABLE_2 
user_id
item_id
date 

TABLE_3 
user_id
item_id
date 

TABLE_4
user_id
item_id
system_name
system_version
date 

TABLE_5 
user_id
item_id
system_name
system_version
date
```

My output table needs to be the following:

```
T_OUTPUT
system_code 
user_id
item_id 
system_name 
system_version
date(latest)
```

I tried using union but since some of the tables don't contain system_name or system_version there will be duplicates when I use group by and get the max date. Furthermore if a table with no system_name or system_version has the latest date then this fields will be null when a previous date already has the system_name and system_version from a different table. For example.

```
TABLE_1
APL, 1234, asdf, MacOS
 
TABLE_2 
1234, asdf, 07-20-2020

TABLE_3 
1234, asdf, 07-20-2020

TABLE_4 
1234, asdf, MacOS, Catalina, 07-15-2020

TABLE_5 
1234, asdf, MacOS, NULL, 07-15-2020
```

The output should be

```
APL, 1234, asdf, MacOS, Catalina, 07-20-2020
```

I was also thinking of using a stored procedure to merge into the target table and insert and update based on the user_id and item_id. I am fairly new to SQL so Im not sure if there is a way to do this is SQL or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
with t as (
      select system_code, user_id, item_id, system_name, null as system_version, date
      from table1
      union all
      select null, user_id, item_id, null, null, date
      from table2
      union all
      select null, user_id, item_id, null, null, date
      from table3
      union all
      select null, user_id, item_id, system_name, system_version, date
      from table4
      union all
      select null, user_id, item_id, system_name, system_version, date
      from table5
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id, item_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I'm not sure this works entirely as it will still return NULL values for records if the tables that don't have system_name and system_version have the latest date. If the record exists in say table4 or table5 with system_name and system_version and has an older date I want to keep the latest date that could be in say table3 but also keep the system_name and system_version from table4 or table5 and not override it as NULL since its already there and its the same user and item.